# Projective points of a Fermat Curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, coding-theory

This is a problem from my coding theory book which I am trying to wrap my head around.

Consider the curve $f_3F(q)$ given by $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$

A) Find the three projective points (x:y:z) of $P^2(F_2)$ on $f_3(F_2)$

B) Find the nine projective points (x:y:z) of $P^2(F_4)$ on $f_3(F_4)$

Attempt:

A) I think the answer is (1:0:1);(1:1:0);(0:1:1).

B) I am getting a little stuck here since there are 16 points which hold with the curve. I know that we have to concern ourselves with equivalences here but when I look at equivalences I end up with only 6 points not 9.

Work part B) Since $1^3 = 1$  $2^3 = 0$ and $3^3 = 3$ over $F_4$

(1:0:3)~(2:0:2)~(3:0:1) ; (1:2:3)~(2:0:2)~(3:2:1) ; (1:3:0)~(2:2:0)~(3:1:0) ; (1:3:2)~(2:2:0)~(3:1:2) ; (0:1:3)~(0:2:2)~(0:3:1) ; (2:1:3)~(0:2:2)~(2:3:1) ; (3:1:0)~(2:2:0)~(1:3:0)

So what am I missing/doing wrong here?

Comment: Note that $1=3$ holds in $\Bbb{F}_4$. Maybe you are confusing $\Bbb{F}_4$ with $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$?

Comment: Your answer to part A) is correct, by the way.

Comment: Yes I had confused this, I just looked up the tables for $F_4$, is it not true then that all elements of $F_4$ cubed are 1? If that is so all of my part B are wrong.

Comment: Yes, all of your part B is wrong. It is the right approach though. And it is true that the cube of any non-zero element of $\Bbb{F}_4$ equals $1$.

Comment: So $F_4$ = 0,1,A,B. Then, 1+1=0;A+A=0;B+B=0; are the only things that work. So we have (1:0:1)(1:1:0)(0:1:1)(A:0:A)(A:A:0)(0:A:A)(B:0:B)(B:B:0)(0:B:B) as the points?

Comment: Note that $(1:0:1)=(A:0:A)=(B:0:B)$, and similarly for the other six points.

Comment: So in the end I have 3 points so far only.

Comment: Excepting that there are no one or three-tuples which work with $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ other than (0:0:0) which are not projective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key ideas are already in the comments, so just wrapping this up.

Indeed for the finite field $\Bbb{F}_4=\{0,1,A,B\}$, where $B=A+1=A^2$ we have that any non-zero element cubed is equal to $1$. Thus the equation $x^3+y^3+z^3=0$ forces exactly one of the projective coordinates to be zero.

If, say, $z=0, x\neq0\neq y$, then we can scale $x$ to be $=1$, and then have three different choices, $1,A,B$, for $y$ each giving a solution and a distinct point of the projective plane. The same thing happens when $y=0$ and when $x=0$, and we can scale the first non-zero homogeneous coordinate to $=1$.

This gives us the following nine points:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
(1:1:0),&(1:A:0),&(1:B:0),\\
(1:0:1),&(1:0:A),&(1:0:B),\\
(0:1:1),&(0:1:A),&(0:1:B).
\end{array}
$$